# How to remove the subtitle of a frame in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I'm using an already avaialble template of my university, and at the start of every frame there is the subtitle even if I don't write the \framesubtitle{} command. How can I remove such occurrence?

EDIT: https://www.overleaf.com/read/ybqzjzxhrvhr this is the source.

Comment: Please show a minimal reproducible example. That's not default beamer behaviour so we will need to see a reproducible example to see where in the code this comes from. You have both your presentation code and your template, we don't. We would need to have crystal ball to solve your problem with the information you give us.

Comment: Let me know if you need more code or info

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to your project. However please note that questions on tex.se should be self-sustained. This will ensure that your question is still useful for future users with the same problem even in case your link is not longer available. It would be better if you could make a short example document and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme modifies the `\beamer@checkframetitle` macro to automatically add a subtitle. You can revert to the original beamer definition:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{sintef}

\makeatletter
  \def\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{frametitle}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]